# Jest leaks memory allocating strings for imported files

Tags: memory-leaks, jestjs

I'm trying to understand why my jest tests are leaking memory but I've not idea what can be the cause. Looks like jest allocates a huge amount of strings (seems the imports) but I don't understand why they do that.

I start the tests disabling module cache:

```
node --inspect-brk --expose-gc ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --logHeapUsage --no-cache
```

and I get the following output:
[image]
as you see, there are tons of MB allocated for module contents.

Any idea how can I try to reduce that amount of memory?

Comment: were you able to come up with a fix?

Comment: Upgrading to latest jest fixed the issue

Comment: Updating  jest to v28 didn't work for me

Comment: Anyone made any progress on this?

I'm seeing node leak ~100MB per test file...

Answer (score 2):

This memory leak is actually a [memory leak in Node's vm.Script()](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40014), which hasn't been resolved yet. Replacing `vm.Script()` by `vm.compileFunctions()` in [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/12205) couldn't be merged as it breaks a test. But this change was published as [jest-runtime](https://github.com/reside-eng/jest-runtime) and can be used as a temporary workaround.

Unfortunately, this workaround seems to skew code coverage results, at least when using the v8 code coverage provider.

Comment: We weren't using TS on that project and ts-jest was not installed at all

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is not related to TypeScript. I assumed that the strings were containing transpiled TypeScript code, but it's actually containing the final JavaScript code to be executed by Node via [vm.Script()](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#new-vmscriptcode-options). I'll update my answer.